# Right EvTerm for `a ~ b`

Tags: haskell, types, plugins, ghc

If I have two types `data L` and `data H`, and I want to "pretend" that I've solved (`H ~ L` or `L ~ H`) in a type checker plugin, what's the right `EvTerm` to use? The two types don't have any constructors, so they should be coercible. I've been using `evCoercion $ mkReflCo Phantom anyTy` and it doesn't panic... but I don't know if that's the right choice.

Comment: I suspect that GHC would start yelling at you if you enabled Core typechecking (`-dcore-lint`). I further suspect you'd need to create a new "coercion axiom" (I think that's `CoAxiom`) in order to do this properly. Not sure how to actually do that, though `GHCPlugins` seems to have some related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to pretend, you can always use a [universal coercion  `UnivCo`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-9.4.2/docs/GHC-Core-TyCo-Rep.html#v:UnivCo), with a plugin provenance.